# MySQL randomize selection query by 1 filed

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have table **my_table**

```
id  type  info
1    1    car
2    1    bicycle
3    1    train
4    2    ketchup
5    2    mustard
6    2    soda
7    3    flower
8    3    tree
9    3    grass
```

I need to make selection query that will order data by type so that results come out like

```
type info
1    car
2    ketchup
3    flower

1    bicycle
2    mustard
3    tree

1    train
2    soda
3    grass
```

Now

```
SELECT * from my_table ORDER BY type ASC
```

does order by type 111 222 333 and i need type 123 123 123.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have windowing functions, so this is more awkward than it would be in other databases.

```
SELECT type, info
FROM (
    SELECT @rank := IF(type=@type, @rank+1, 1) AS rank, @type:=type AS type, info
    FROM (SELECT @rank:=0, @type:=null) _init, my_table
    ORDER BY type, id
) t
ORDER BY rank, type;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83f9d0/1)

Comment: Kewl it does work. Wish it was easier, but i can live with this. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing, i cant understand whats that character "t" for?

Comment: Any derived-table subquery requires a table alias.